# How to leave fullPage.js and continue navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

Example: http://www.hugeinc.com/

I have a portfolio website with a few slides about different projects. After that I'd like the user to continue navigating through other sections, but with normal scrolling (not the fullPage effect).

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">
     <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1"> Slide 1 </div>
     <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2"> Slide 2 </div>
     <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide3"> Slide 3 </div>
     <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide4"> Slide 4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After the finish fullpage div it stops scrolling, but the page still has an about and contact sections

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/) for that purpose. The small brother of fullpage.js.

I [created an article about how to create a website like hugeinc using pagePiling.js](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2015/04/09/how-to-create-a-beautiful-fullscreen-single-scrolling-page-like-huge-inc/).

If you are just worried about the scrolling functionality in fullpage.js you should be using `scrollOverflow:true` as in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Comment: thanks a lot, @alvaro! and great tutorial as well :)